# C++ ffmpeg extract audio to mp3 (demuxing)

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I am trying to write a C++ program that allows me to extract the audio from a video file to an mp3 file. I searched the internet and stackoverflow, but couldn't get it to work.

The library I chose is **ffmpeg** and I have to do it in C/C++. This is what I have so far.

```
// Step 1 - Register all formats and codecs
avcodec_register_all();
av_register_all();

AVFormatContext* fmtCtx = avformat_alloc_context();

// Step 2 - Open input file, and allocate format context
if(avformat_open_input(&fmtCtx, filePath.toLocal8Bit().data(), NULL, NULL) < 0)
    qDebug() << "Error while opening " << filePath;

// Step 3 - Retrieve stream information
if(avformat_find_stream_info(fmtCtx, NULL) < 0)
    qDebug() << "Error while finding stream info";

// Step 4 - Find the audiostream
audioStreamIdx = -1;
for(uint i=0; i<fmtCtx->nb_streams; i++) {
    if(fmtCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
        audioStreamIdx = i;
        break;
    }
}

if(audioStreamIdx != -1) {
    // Step 5
    AVCodec *aCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MP3);
    AVCodecContext *audioDecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(aCodec);

    avcodec_open2(audioDecCtx, aCodec, NULL);

    // Step 6
    AVPacket pkt;
    AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();

    av_init_packet(&pkt);

    pkt.data = NULL;
    pkt.size = 0;

    int got_packet = 0;

    while(av_read_frame(fmtCtx, &pkt) == 0) {
        int got_frame = 0;

        int ret = avcodec_decode_audio4(audioDecCtx, frame, &got_frame, &pkt);

        if(got_frame) {
            qDebug() << "got frame";
        }
    }

    av_free_packet(&pkt);
}

avformat_close_input(&fmtCtx);
```

But the error I get when executing avcodec_decode_audio4() is "[mp3 @ 825fc30] Header missing".

Thanks in advance!

[EDIT]
I found out that the audio of the video was not MP3 but AAC. So I changed Step 5 to the following lines of code

```
    // Step 5
    AVCodecContext *audioDecCtx = fmtCtx->streams[audioStreamIdx]->codec;
    AVCodec *aCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(audioDecCtx->codec_id);

    avcodec_open2(audioDecCtx, aCodec, NULL);
```

Now it outputs "got frame" and the avcodec_decode_audio4() returns the number of bytes it decoded.

Now I have to write the audio to a file, preferably to an MP3 file. I found out that I have to do it with the function avcodec_encode_audio2(). But some extra help on how to use it is more then welcome!

Comment: Are you sure you want to output to an MP3 file? That would imply transcoding from one lossy audio format to another. Perhaps you just want an uncompressed PCM file?

Comment: Hi Mike. Yes I really want an MP3 file. The reason for this is that I'm extracting the audio out of music videos.

Comment: Made a new topic with some extra code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537641/c-ffmpeg-mp4-to-mp3-transcoding

Comment: are you able to solve your problem?